# ZRANGEBYLEX command on redis using jedis api doesnot return any result

Tags: redis, jedis

Below command return expected result (places names having prefix '**new alban**') when executed in the REDIS CLI.

*127.0.0.1:6379> **zrangebylex** my_places_data_set "[new alban" "[**new alban**\xff"*

1. "new albany f..."
2. "new albany p..."
3. "new albany r..."

But when this command is called using jedis api, it's not returning any result for above prefix but returns if i complete the word.

NO RESULT - *pipeline.**zrangeByLex**(my_places_data_set, "[new alban", "[**new alban**\xff", 0, 5);*

RETURN RESULT - *pipeline.**zrangeByLex**(my_places_data_set, "[new albany", "[**new albany**\xff", 0, 5);*

If i use xff instead of \xff following happens

NO RESULT - *pipeline.**zrangeByLex**(my_places_data_set, "[new alban", "[**new alban**xff", 0, 5);*

RETURN RESULT - *pipeline.**zrangeByLex**(my_places_data_set, "[new albany", "[**new albany**xff", 0, 5);*

RETURN RESULT - *pipeline.**zrangeByLex**(my_places_data_set, "[new albany", "[**new alba**xff", 0, 5);*

P.S. Jedis api signature : *zrangeByLex(String key, String min, String max, int offset, int count)*

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by manually appending hex code to prefix

```
byte[] prefixByte = ("[" + prefix).getBytes();
byte[] prefixByteExtended = Arrays.copyOf(prefixByte, prefixByte.length + 1);
prefixByteExtended[prefixByte.length] = (byte) 0xFF;
pipeline.zrangeByLex(my_places_data_set, ("[" + prefix), new String(prefixByteExtended), 0, 5));
```